# event listener not returning object property on all event types

Tags: javascript, events, foreach

```js
const stars=document.querySelectorAll('.star')
    const message=document.querySelector('.message')
    const mouseEvents=["mouseover", "mouseout", "click"]
    //creating star object
    //add event listeners as array
    
    
    stars.forEach((star, i)=> {
      star.starNum=(i+1)
      console.log(star.starNum)
      mouseEvents.forEach((event)=> {
        star.addEventListener(event, starRate)
      })
    })
    
    
    function starRate(e) {
      let num=e.target.starNum
      console.log(num)
    }
```

```css
 ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .star {
      display: inline-block;
      color: #ddd;
      font-size: 2.5em;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
      </head>
      <body>
    
        <ul class="stars">
          <li class="star"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
          <li class="star"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
          <li class="star"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
          <li class="star"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
          <li class="star"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="message">Message</div>
        
      </body>
    
      <script src="app.js"></script>
      
    </html>
```

I applied multiple events to each star element. But whenever I **click** or **mouseover** a star, it doesn't return the value of its starNum property as it's supposed to from the **starRate** function. It only returns a number when you mouseover it. Why is that?

Comment: Please include the code for `starNum` property and the object it belongs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The target property of the Event interface is a reference to the
>   object that dispatched the event.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

This means that you have access to the dom element and cannot access the property you want.  You can pass this property in one of two ways.

**First way**: Using `data-*` attribute [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Modify your html to include the data you want

```
 <li class="star" data-starnumber="1"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
```

In your javascript, you can reference the data directly.

```
function starRate(e) {
  const num = e.target.dataset.starnumber;
  console.log(num);
}
```

**Second Way**: Bind the data you need to the callback [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

You can bind the data you want to be present in your function call.

```
stars.forEach((star, i) => {
  star.starNum = i+1;
  console.log(star.starNum);
  mouseEvents.forEach((event) => {
    star.addEventListener(event, starRate.bind(null, star);
  });
});

function starRate(star, e) {
  const num = star.starNum;
  console.log(num);
}
```

Comment: @Bob when the event is called, the argument that is supplied is an `Event`.  This event is generated by the browser and has no knowledge of the modification you made to `star`.  You are adding a property to a dom element.  When the event is fired, the `target` is provided from the dom and does not contain the property you set.

Comment: @Bob Ah, because the `i` tag is cpaturing the event and bubbling to the parent where the event listener is.  By preventing the child (`fa-star`) from handling the events, you deal directly with the dom element that you modified and added the property to.

Comment: @Bob you are attempting to add arbitrary properties to an object that is outside of your control and touched by many things.  My answer is to move the property to somewhere you can control more easily.  In my opinion, this will make your logic more straightforward and easier to read and reason about.  There is nothing wrong with what you are doing, but I believe my methods are more maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

[ChrisG's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58238613/2813224) involving `data-*` attributes is the best solution. This answer is to expand upon the event aspect to the solution.

An important programming pattern called Event Delegation should be used when there multiple event targets (ie *item* -- aka `li.star`). Instead of having each element listen for an event -- assign their *"parent"* element (ie *list* -- aka `ul.stars`) to listen for an event for all of them. By doing the following you can use one element to listen for an event triggered on any of its descendant elements (an unlimited amount).

- Register an event to an element that all elements concerned (ie all `li.star` -- for now on each one will be referred to as *item*) share as a common ancestor (`ul.stars` -- for now on referred to as *list*)
- The callback function must pass the Event Object

  **Example:**

  ```
  function starRate(event) {...
  ```

  or

  ```
  function starRate(e) {...
  ```
- Use `if/else if` control statements with the Event Object properties in order to isolate items. The most important event properties are:

  **`.target`**: Always references the actual element that was clicked, hovered over, etc. (ie *item*)

  **`.currentTarget`**: Always references the element that listens for the event (ie *list*)

  **Example:**

  ```
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {...
  ```

  Interpreted as: *"if the element that event was triggered on **IS NOT** the element listening to the event..."*

Refer to this article on [Event Delegation](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm)

Further details are commented in demo below
**Note:** The event in demo is *`mouseover`* only since all other pointer events call the same callback function (ie `starRate()`).

```js
// [list]
// Reference the element that is the parent of all stars (ul.stars)
const list = document.querySelector('.stars');
// [item]
// Collect all the stars into a NodeList (li.star)
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.star');
// [message]
// Reference the message display element (output.message)
const message = document.querySelector('.message')

// Register the mouseover event to the parent element
// The Event Object will reference [list] as e.currentTarget
list.addEventListener("mouseover", starRate);

// Assign to each [item] the attribute 'data-star-num'
// Set each 'data-star-num' value corresponding to it's index +1
items.forEach((star, index) => {
  star.dataset.starNum = index + 1;
});

// Pass Event Object (e)
function starRate(e) {
  // e.target is the actual element being hovered over [item]
  // e.currentTarget is the element to which the event is registered to [list]
  // if the hovered over element [item] IS NOT [list]...
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
    // and if the [item] has the attribute 'data-star-num'...
    if (e.target.hasAttribute('data-star-num')) {
      // get the value of that [item]'s 'data-star-num' value
      // converting it to a real number is optional
      let num = parseInt(e.target.dataset.starNum);
      // Log value to console
      console.log(num);
      // Display value on [message]
      message.textContent = num;
    }
  }
  // Otherwise terminate function
  // This statement also prevents the event from bubbling any further
  return false;
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.star {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ddd;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">

</head>

<body>

  <ul class="stars">
    <li class="star"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li class="star"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li class="star"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li class="star"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li class="star"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
  </ul>
  <output class="message">Message</output>

</body>

</html>
```